# objectDeleted()/objectModified() Event in stateless session in Drool

Tags: drools

I am new to drools.
Is/When objectDeleted()/objectModified() Event in stateless session in Drool  invoked? 
I have added DebugRuleRuntimeEventListener() but can't see any objectDeleted() or object Modified() event getting raised.

Comment: There is no point in tracking these events in a *stateless* session. Use a stateful session.

Comment: I need to track them for some visualisation activity.

Comment: Try using a stateful session. Although, I'd like to see complete, executable code that demonstrates your original problem.